# Ways to compress resources and/or files in Asset folders?

Tags: android, memory, compression, assets

I am approaching finishing my application. My asset folder has over 20 PDF files in it, and obviously they are taking up quite a bit of space. Is there a way I can compress these files to make the Application smaller? What are other good techniques for checking / lowering memory consumption in my code / throughout my project? Thanks in advance for any input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You could zip your files then decrompress when needed**

1. **Here's a tutorial** [Zip programmatically with Android](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Zipping_Files_with_Android_%28Programmatically%29)
2. **Check the** [java.util.zip class](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/package-summary.html) , it provides both zip & gzip functionality for compression and decompression.
3. You could also download the pdfs from another site once the application is installed

**Or This Should work:**

```
    /*
 * 
 * Zips a file at a location and places the resulting zip file at the toLocation
 * Example: zipFileAtPath("downloads/myfolder", "downloads/myFolder.zip");
 */

public boolean zipFileAtPath(String sourcePath, String toLocation) {
    // ArrayList<String> contentList = new ArrayList<String>();
    final int BUFFER = 2048;


    File sourceFile = new File(sourcePath);
    try {
        BufferedInputStream origin = null;
        FileOutputStream dest = new FileOutputStream(toLocation);
        ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(
                dest));
        if (sourceFile.isDirectory()) {
            zipSubFolder(out, sourceFile, sourceFile.getParent().length());
        } else {
            byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER];
            FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(sourcePath);
            origin = new BufferedInputStream(fi, BUFFER);
            ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(getLastPathComponent(sourcePath));
            out.putNextEntry(entry);
            int count;
            while ((count = origin.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) != -1) {
                out.write(data, 0, count);
            }
        }
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

/*
 * 
 * Zips a subfolder
 * 
 */

private void zipSubFolder(ZipOutputStream out, File folder,
        int basePathLength) throws IOException {

    final int BUFFER = 2048;

    File[] fileList = folder.listFiles();
    BufferedInputStream origin = null;
    for (File file : fileList) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            zipSubFolder(out, file, basePathLength);
        } else {
            byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER];
            String unmodifiedFilePath = file.getPath();
            String relativePath = unmodifiedFilePath
                    .substring(basePathLength);
            Log.i("ZIP SUBFOLDER", "Relative Path : " + relativePath);
            FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(unmodifiedFilePath);
            origin = new BufferedInputStream(fi, BUFFER);
            ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(relativePath);
            out.putNextEntry(entry);
            int count;
            while ((count = origin.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) != -1) {
                out.write(data, 0, count);
            }
            origin.close();
        }
    }
}

/*
 * gets the last path component
 * 
 * Example: getLastPathComponent("downloads/example/fileToZip");
 * Result: "fileToZip"
 */
public String getLastPathComponent(String filePath) {
    String[] segments = filePath.split("/");
    String lastPathComponent = segments[segments.length - 1];
    return lastPathComponent;
}
```